# Вид сказуемого

Tags: синтаксис

Сказуемое "нет" каким сказуемым является: ПГС, СГС или СИС?

Answer (score 2):

Это особенное слово и особенное сказуемое. Похоже на простое глагольное (не есть, не имеется), но так как слово НЕТ глаголом  не является, а именем тем более, то и говорим просто: сказуемое выражено словом НЕТ.

НЕТ. Искон. Сращение др.-рус. эпохи не (есть) тъ, где тъ (или ту, ср. нету) является усилительный местоименной частицей. Ср. нетути. См. тут.
Яндекс.Словари › Этимологический словарь. — 2004

НЕТ.  безл., в знач. сказуемого (заменяет отсутствующее в русском языке наст. вр. от гл. быть с отриц.), кого-чего. Не имеется налицо, не существует вовсе. У меня нет времени. 
dic.academic.ru › Толковый словарь Ушакова

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы правы, Екатерина. В безличном предложении - это ПГС.  См. напр.: Е. И. Литневская Русский язык: краткий теоретический курс для школьников.